# Using HLOOKUP for date values

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the `HLOOKUP` function working in my sheet but it's not working like it should.

The function is:

```
=HLOOKUP(TEXT(NOW(), "yyyy-MM-dd"), INDIRECT(TEXT(NOW(), "MMMM") & "!B1:AE5"), 3, FALSE)
```

Translating the functions, that would be:

```
=HLOOKUP("2015-07-01", July!B1:AE5, 3, FALSE)
```

I get an error however:

> Did not find value '2015-07-01' in HLOOKUP evaluation

That doesn't make sense since `'2015-07-01'` is in cell B1 in the sheet, July.
Why isn't it working and what can I do to fix it?

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1texFm_8_P06im1hs0zZ3EDg4-hc2rlJ2G-PM__Ns_PQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: See if the value you look up (in July!B1:AE5) is formatted as text or date ?

Comment: @JPV Formatted as a date. I also tried `TEXT(NOW(), "M/d/yyyy")` as the search key though.

Comment: Why don't you share an example document with us, so we can have a look?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Spedwards: you are looking for a text value, but what needs to be found is in a date-format.  Can you share an example sheet ?

Comment: @jpv see comments, example sheet added

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by changing the Search Criteria from `TEXT(NOW(), "yyyy-MM-dd")` to `TODAY()`